# Get Brake pedal position from generic ELM 327 BLE OBD dongle

Tags: brakes, obd-ii

What is the code to get the brake pedal position using the generic ODD2 (ELM327) dongle

Comment: What information do you get about brakes from your elm327?

Answer (score 1):

The ELM 327 is just a common IC used to interface the OBD II with a PC or mobile phone. It has absolutely no clue about the data sent in either direction. That's the job of the software you use.

Next, the OBD II port provides lots of information in a standardized, known protocol. That means the way to read out for example RPM, speed and error codes is the same among all cars of all brands, and there are thousands of apps out there, which can display that data.

The port also allows access to many other data an functions, but the protocol to access that is not public, and is specific to each manufacturer. One need special software to use this. There may even be some kind of password protection / encryption, so listening the special software talking with the car does not help to find out how to access that data.

**If** brake pedal pressure is available via OBD II, it is not in the open part of the protocol. You'll need the specialized software from the manufacturer or from a licensed vendor.